# How do i compare a [null] list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, expression

I have a list which is returning `[null]` but I want to replace that with `[]`

I'm using `useEffect()` but I'm literally not able to find an expression that returns true when compared with `null`.

I've tried:

```
listToCompare === null // false
listToCompare[0] === null // false
listToCompare === undefined // false
listToCompare === [null] // error even before compiling
```

This is irritating because `[null]` returns `.length` as `1` when I need it to be 0.

Can someone help me find an expression to return true when compared to [null]

Really confused on what a `[null]` list even is :(

Comment: You can use `if (list[0] === null) { list.splice(0, 1); }`, to remove the  array element which has a value of `null` (at index `0`);

Comment: `[null]` is an array with one entry, and that entry’s value is `null`. Your second attempt (`list[0] === null`) should return true for this. Perhaps you’re testing for it before the null entry is present? Could the null be added afterward? You could filter out nulls via `const filtered = list.filter(Boolean)`.

Comment: @ray that's what i thought but list[0] === null doesn't return true :/ the filter logic works tho :)

Comment: @Nick Where `list = [null]` comparing `list[0] === null` does return `true` indeed, so I can't reproduce your error? And in the post `list === [null]` which is: 2 objects compared by reference and **not** by value; they only happen to have the same value to the human eye, but under the hood of JavaScript *something* like `0.01x === 0.02x` comparison is happening; where `0.01x` is a memory address for `list`'s value, and the `0.02x` is an address for `[null]` in the memory.

Comment: As for the second part of your question, it seem like you have things confused with Python *Lists* terms? In JavaScript `[]` is called Array literal - a non-primitive data type, whereas `null` is a primitive data, and `[null]` is an Array with ***one*** element - that element is `null`, hence why `[null].length` returns `1`; and `[null][0]` would access the 1st element - that is: an element at index `0` and will return `null` - the primitive data type.

Comment: @Aleksandar `list[0] === null` always returns false when the list is `[null]`. i don't understand why but it's the behavior I'm experiencing

`newValue[0] === null ? something : somethingElse` is the exact condition I'm using where newValue is the list. it never executes `something` even when the list is [null] ... also list is never equal to [null]. I get [null] when I use JSON.stringify(newValue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
const listToCompare = [null];
const isNull = !listToCompare.filter(Boolean).length

console.log(isNull) // returns true
```

Comment: If the `listToCompare` is `[0]` or `[false]`, this will return true as well

Comment: Same goes for `['']` and `[undefined]`.

Comment: @ro the list can never be 0 or false or '' due to the nature of the list ... each list is typed as typed Option and and Option[] can never be 0/false/''/undefined ... 

if i